# Flask secret_key is unavailable when using Gunicorn, even though it's configured

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm trying to deploy a simple flask app. Then I choose gunicorn and nginx.
But when I tryed the app just with gunicorn running, the follow exception appears:

```
RuntimeError: the session is unavailable because no secret key was set.  Set the secret_key on the application to something unique and secret.
```

`init.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = config["secret-key"]
    app.run(port=config["port"], host=config["host"], debug=config["debug"])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of the `__name__` guard is so that code won't execute when the module is imported.  WSGI servers import your module and uses the Flask app callable, so that code doesn't get executed.  Move the config outside of the `__name__` guard.